# MouseEnter/MouseLeave on RowDefinition

Tags: c#, wpf, grid, mouseenter

I want to do this:

https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/f50aeda2f73b47c47664e3651c638ba624418b8b

See how, as your mouse cursor moves over the lines of source code, an image/button appears to the left of the table? That.

So I have a Grid, and RowDefinition has MouseEnter and MouseLeave events.  Turns out these events are useless and can never fire (please correct me if I'm wrong here), because they require a Background property (even if it's Transparent), and RowDefinition doesn't have a Background property.

I can't just hook MouseEnter on every element in every cell, because by the time I've moved my mouse the newly visible button will have already disappeared.

How can I get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` aren't actually in the Visual Tree since they are `FrameworkContentElements` (rather than `FrameworkElements`) and that's why they don't raise any mouse events, they aren't `Visuals`. They are just used by the `Grid` to position its childs.

One approach that comes to mind is to use the Attached Events `Mouse.MouseMove` and `Mouse.MouseLeave` on the `Grid` to get notified when these events are raised for any child in the `Grid` or the `Grid` itself.

```
<Grid Mouse.MouseMove="Grid_MouseMove"
      Mouse.MouseLeave="Grid_MouseLeave"
      Background="Transparent">
```

In the `Mouse.MouseMove` event handler we can get the relative mouse position to the `Grid` and calculate which `RowDefinition` is currently being hoovered by the mouse and store that in an Attached Property, like `MouseOverRowDefinition`.

```
private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = sender as Grid;
    Point mousePoint = e.GetPosition(grid);
    double heightSum = grid.RowDefinitions[0].ActualHeight;
    int activeRow = 0;
    for (; heightSum < mousePoint.Y; activeRow++)
    {
        heightSum += grid.RowDefinitions[activeRow].ActualHeight;
    }
    GridExtensions.SetMouseOverRowDefinition(grid, activeRow);
}
// No RowDefinition is beeing hoovered, set MouseOverRowDefinition to -1
private void Grid_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Grid grid = sender as Grid;
    GridExtensions.SetMouseOverRowDefinition(grid, -1);
}
```

Now we can query the `Grid` for the `MouseOverRowDefinition` so the rest is just a matter of comparing `Grid.Row` for the `Image` to `MouseOverRowDefinition` for the `Grid` to decide if it should be `Visible` or not.

Uploaded a small sample app that does this here if you want to try it out:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/39657172/MouseOverGridRowDefinition.zip

Comment: Thanks for the example project!  I'm still trying to get the multibinding xaml to work in code though, I'm a little lost...